# SQL Query Help Needed with custom column

Tags: sql-server, join, union

Table structures are as follows:

```
Sales: Sales_id, sDate,ccode,qty,amt;     
Challan: Ch_id, ch_date,qty,amt;
```

Information required is:

```
Id | Date | CCode | Type | Qty | Amt

If sales then type = sales; if challan then type = challan ; order by date
```

I have tried the following:

```
select s.cust_code,s.cust_name,s.sales_qty,s.sales_amt,c.cust_code,
c.cust_name,c.challan_qty ,c.challan_amt 
from sales s inner 
join challan c on s.sales_date  = c.challan_date
```

How should I put a custom column of type and show challan or sales on particular date ?

Comment: How to figure out if its a sales or a challan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for union statement:

```
select 
  Sales_id as Id, sDate as [date], ccode as CCode, 
  'sales' as Type, qty as Qty, amt as Amt
From Sales
Union
select
  Ch_id as Id, ch_date as [date], Null as CCode, 
  'Challan' as Type, qty as Qty, amt as Amt
from Challan
```

Comment: Even if he is trying to do union this query is wrong as it will show Sales as a type in both the cases.